# Returns the contents of a scrollview to its initial position SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, zstack

Hi everyone I'm working on a horizontal scrolling with views placed inside a `ZStack`

The positions of the overlapping views are handled by an `offset` like this

```
Test1(currentIndex: $currentIndex, size: size)
    .offset(x: -size.width * CGFloat((currentIndex - view)))
```

In overlay above the `ZStack` I added a **"Next" button** which assigns a value of **+1** to the variable `currentIndex` in order to manage the view display

Everything seems to work fine but I have a problem that I would like to be able to solve.

Each view that is presented has a `scrollview` which manages the content of the view .

I'll give you an example for convenience in this example I will call the views by assigning the `currentIndex` value for you to understand better:

[image]

The first view is presented when `currentIndex == 0`. The user scrolls the contents of **View0** and pushes the **next** button to show the view with `currentIndex == 1` (**View1**).

If the user returns to `currentIndex == 0` by pushing the back button, the contents of **View0** **remain in the position where the user left it** ...

[image]

At this point I would like that when the user navigates between the views and goes back to the previous view (for a modification of the data that he has entered) the contents of the scrollview return to the initial position and not as he left it before pushing the next button

I hope I was able to explain myself well if you need information because I wasn't clear enough, just ask

---

This is my code

```
struct Test1: View {
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    var size: CGSize
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                    Text("Title ")
                        .font(.comfortaa(.bold, size: .title))
                    Text("Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo")
                        .font(.comfortaa(.regular, size: .body))
                }
                .lineSpacing(5)
                
                ForEach(0..<10, id:\.self) { _ in
                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke()
                        .frame(height: 100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ExamInsertionView: View {
    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            let size = $0.size
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<3, id:\.self) { view in
                    Test1(currentIndex: $currentIndex, size: size)
                        .offset(x: -size.width * CGFloat((currentIndex - view)))
                        .animation(.interactiveSpring, value: currentIndex)
                }
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                HStack {
                Button("Back") {
                    if currentIndex > 0 {
                        currentIndex -= 1
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Avanti") {
                    if currentIndex < 2 {
                        currentIndex += 1
                    } else { currentIndex = 0 }
                }
            }
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(24)
            .background(.blue)
            .padding(.bottom, 40)
            }
        }
    }
}
```